# Rails 4.1.2 not loading one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some behavior that I'm having trouble tracking down. I have an AR model `Comment`.

I've also nested a handful of models under the `Comment` namespace:

```
app/models/comment
├── digest
│   └── bulk.rb
├── digest.rb
├── notification
│   └── router.rb
└── notification.rb
```

When I run my test suite, I get failures like this:

```
  6) Error:
Comment::NotificationTest#test_sends_2_emails_to_others_when_a_3rd_party_comments:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    test/models/comment/notification_test.rb:37:in `initialize'
    test/models/comment/notification_test.rb:37:in `new'
    test/models/comment/notification_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:NotificationTest>'
```

It turns out the `app/models/comment/notification.rb` file isn't being loaded at all. If I put a `binding.pry` line at the top of the test and say `require "comment/notification"` it returns back true. Once it's loaded before the test, all the tests pass.

If I put a `binding.pry` line at the top of `app/models/comment/notification.rb`, it never gets hit.

The weird thing is, the other files in the hierarchy are being loaded properly: `app/models/comment/digest.rb`, `app/models/comment/notification/router.rb`, etc.

Another weird thing is if I run the `test/models/comment/notifications_test.rb` on its own, the tests pass just fine. Only when I run the whole suite together, or just `rake test:models` does it fail and never load that file.

I looked hard at the names and all seems fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What is in router.rb?

Comment: Just a simple PORO class that routes notifications to either email or an internal database table.

Comment: To be precise does it define a class or module called Notification (inside which Router is nested)?

Comment: Ah, you've reached that conclusion too.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is the result of Rails autoloading quirkiness. I have to explicitly require the file in the test because the other constant that's in the `Notification` namespace has already been loaded, so it doesn't hit the `const_missing` flow and try to look up the file.